# How to replace data in one column in a table with data from a column in another table?

Tags: mysql, database

I have a table called users that has first_name and last_name columns and I want to shuffle the values in these columns so the names are no longer identifiable as real people.

I thought one way to achieve this would be to create a shuffle table, which takes the value from each column ordered randomly and then sets those values back into the users table, but I can't seem to get that to work.

The code I've tried is:

```
CREATE TABLE shuffle SELECT first_name FROM users ORDER BY RAND();
INSERT INTO users (first_name) SELECT first_name FROM shuffle;
```

I don't get any error messages when I run this, but it doesn't do what I'm wanting. Is this the right approach? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to update columns in user table, this should work
`UPDATE users SET first_name=(SELECT first_name FROM users ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1)`
but I'm a little bit confused, because in your query you use users2 table, which I don't know what is. Is it copy, or temporary table? Do you need update user table or create a copy of table with shuffled values?

Comment: Sorry, yeah it should just be users, changed it in my example.

When I run your suggestion I get 'You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '() LIMIT 1)' at line 1'.

Comment: Fixed typo, there should be rand() instead of random()